# mysqlimport does not finish when importing 56GB file

Tags: mysqlimport

I am importing a couple of big files into a table:

```
/usr/bin/mysqlimport -h myHost -u myUser --delete --local --fields_escaped_by=\\ MBSR -L file1.txt
/usr/bin/mysqlimport -h myHost -u myUser --delete --local --fields_escaped_by=\\ MBSR -L file2.txt
```

One is 56GB and the other one is 36GB.  I imported successfully other tables of up to 17GB in size.  After days, neither of these two big imports seem to be be any close to finishing.

Any suggestions on how to make this work? Also, is there a way to see progress of a mysqlimport?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this import command

```
/usr/bin/mysql -h hostname -u Username -p databasename < "path to local database file.sql"
```